# How can I make shami kabab without chana dal

Tags: substitutions, pulses

[Shami kabab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shami_kebab) are patties traditionally made with minced meat and chickpeas (chana daal).

What could be a substitute for the chana daal that still produces reasonably similar results.

Comment: Just a few hints how you can easily improve your posts: Add some explanation about the topic. Use the English names, at least in addition to the local names. Explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

More than likely another bean that has a firm texture like Chickpeas. People use black beans for vegetarian hamburgers because or their firmness.